# Optimize/fit data for 2 variables described by three functions

Tags: fitting

I have three equations that describe how parameters change:
$$N_{1}(T,f)=f \ e^{-T (\sigma^{1}_c +\sigma^{1}_f)}$$
$$N_{2}(T,f)=-\frac{f \sigma^{1}_c \ (e^{-T (\sigma^{1}_c +\sigma^{1}_f)}-e^{-T \sigma^{2}_c})}{\sigma^{1}_c-\sigma^{2}_c+\sigma^{1}_f}$$
$$N_{3}(T,f)=(1-f) \ e^{-T \sigma^{3}_c }$$

```
N1[T_,f_]:=f*Exp[-T*(97 + 584)]
N2[T_,f_]:=-((f*97*(Exp[-T*(97 + 584)] - Exp[-T*(24)]))/(97 - 24 + 584))
N3[T_,f_]:=(1 - f)*Exp[-T*(2.683)]
```

All of the $\sigma$ values are known.  I have the relative values for each $N_i$ and would like to solve for $T$ and $f$.

There is no exact solution, so I'd like to optimize/approximate a solution that finds some $T$ and $f$ which would result in values close to what I have, something like a least squares fit but for three functions rather than data points.

The $N_i$ are concentrations of components, so at some point $F$ and $T$, I know that component $N_1$ is 74% of the solution, $N_2$ is 13% and $N_3$ is 11%.  There are others $N_i$s that make the percentages add to unity, but I don't have equations to describe those, so they're not relevant.

It seems like a pretty simple problem, but I haven't been able to figure out a way to fit the data to multiple functions.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Edit: Yes, for any of the two expression, there is a numerical solution (no free parameters).  But I need to fit the data to all three equations and solve for an f and T that approximate the real data as well as possible.  This would be done with a least squares fit for the parameters f and T, but I'm not sure how to account for equations, rather than data in Mathmatica's least squares function.

Comment: This sounds to me more l like a mathematics([math.se])/statistics question than a *Mathematica* question. Once you know the method by which you want to fit, then you can start to figure out how to implement it in *Mathematica*, and then come here if you run into any trouble in that implementation.

Comment: I'd like to fit by least squares, sorry if that wasn't clear from the post.

Comment: If you could write out what specific objective function you want to optimize around, `NMinimize` would likely be the most straightforward way to solve this problem. Just reading the problem however, I'm not entirely sure what you're going for here. I'd guess it'd be minimizing the sum of square differences between the known $N_i$ values and the corresponding derived values from the $T$ and $f$ expressions.

Comment: Yes, that is the least squares method, I'd like to optimize by minimizing the sum of squared residuals between the real data points and the calculated points (for some f, T).  I was hoping to that someone would know a method to input my equations or some variation of them into Mathmaticas LeastSquares regression analysis.

Comment: @Mecury-197 I'm a bit confused about what you want. What are you trying to fit? You have the $N_i$ values and you have expressions for them and you have the $\sigma$ values so what is there left to fit? Like there are no free parameters in this problem as you've written it out.

Comment: @b3m2a1 f and T are still free and there is no numerical solution.  Therefore, I need to find a solution for f and T that approximates the real data

Comment: @Mecury-197 what are you plotting in that graphic then? It sure looks like you have `T` and `f`

Comment: @b3m2a1 I plotted the functions over a range of possible f and T values to visualize the functions.  Having a range based on a hypothesis is not the same as having a value that best fits my data.  I'll delete the graphic if you think its confusing

Comment: @Mecury-197 it is a little confusing. What data do you have then? I guess that wasn't clear in a rigorous sense either. Could you provide your data and explain what it is?

Comment: Could you also type your functions in Mathematica syntax? That'd make it a lot nicer to work with.

Comment: @b3m2a1 I've updated the question accordingly and added values for the constants plugged into the functions in mathmatica syntax.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I *think* I understand what you want, now. You just want a solution that more or less gives you the right ratios for a single point, right? I.e. you don't need a fit. You just need to minimize the residuals from what you expect for a single point.

So we can try this:

```
systemEquations =
  With[
   {n1 = N1[T, f], n2 = N2[T, f], n3 = N3[T, f], 
    conc = {.74, .13, .11}},
   MapThread[
    # - (#2/Total[conc]) (n1 + n2 + n3) &,
    {
     {n1, n2, n3},
     conc
     }
    ]
   ];

sol = NMinimize[
  Norm@Simplify[systemEquations],
  { T, f} ∈ Rectangle[{0., 0.}, {.003, 1.0}]
  ]

{9.26348*10^-8, {T -> 0.00119307, f -> 0.937932}}
```

Then substituting back in:

```
systemEquations /. sol[[2]]

{7.55255*10^-8, -4.13023*10^-8, -3.42232*10^-8}

{N1[T, f], N2[T, f], N3[T, f]} /. sol[[2]]

{0.416212, 0.0731183, 0.0618693}
```

Seem reasonable?

Comment: Yes, that looks correct!  It seems I came at this from the wrong angle, I was really hoping when I posted this that it would be a trivial problem and I had overlooked something in wolfram documentation about reducing residuals about a point in functions.  So thank you for trying to understand my poor initial explanation and helping me!

Comment: @Mecury-197 I'm glad I could be useful. Keep an eye on this page, though, maybe someone else will come up with an even better answer.

Comment: Alternative `NMinimize[(.74 - N1 [T, f])^2 + (.13 - N2 [T, f])^2 + (.11 - 
     N3 [T, f])^2, {T, f}]` gives a much better result `{N1->0.725246, N2->0.0254578, N3->0.0952181}` !

Comment: @UlrichNeumann do we know that, e.g., `N1[T, f]` should be .74? I thought it was 74% of the total...

Comment: @  b3m2a1 In your question I read "N1 is 74%,...". Perhaps you have to add a constraint `N1[T, f] + N2[T, f] + N3[T, f] == 0.98`

Comment: @UlrichNeumann what question did I ask? In any case maybe something along those lines would be good. Maybe divide my `conc` array by like `.98` or something.

Comment: Sorry , in the question I read...

Comment: @Mecury-197 but $\sum_{i} N_i \ne 1$ right?

Comment: @UlrichNeumann the idea of adding a constraint is good, and I only know the relative ratios, so b3m2a1 is correct in saying that N1 =.74 isn't quite correct,

Comment: @b3m2a1 Yes, the Ni that I gave don't sum to 1, I actually have data about the others though that I could provide if it would help

Comment: These are the experimental values (with more significant figures): 74.7405% N1, 13.458% N2 , 10.8015% N3 and the last one 1% is N4, N5.  I didn't include them in the calculation because the data on their exact percentages isn't very good, they don't effect the others and I don't have an equation to model their behavior.

Comment: @Mecury-197 my updated version where I take `N1 + N2 + N3 == .98` will give you a better result

Comment: @b3m2a1 thanks for the improvement!

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I'm a little bit late. Here I give a direct solution which I proposed in my comments:

```
opt = NMinimize[{(.74 - N1[T, f])^2 + (.13 - N2[T, f])^2 + (.11 - 
   N3[T, f])^2, N1[T, f] + N2[T, f] + N3[T, f] == 0.98}, {T, f}]
(*{0.024073, {T -> 0.000041979, f -> 0.826641}}*)
```

The optimum fits N1&N3 quite well, N2 only poor:

```
{N1[T, f], N2[T, f], N3[T, f]} /. opt[[2]]
{0.803344, 0.00331672, 0.173339}
```

The approbiate weighting of the funcional might chnage the optimum slightly.

**addenum**

If

```
sumN = N1[T, f] + N2[T, f] + N3[T, f] + \[CapitalDelta]N
```

is the total number of molecules (`unknown  \[CapitalDelta]N`),  the percentage part of each sort of molecules is given by `Ni/sumN`.

Now let's minimize for `T,f **and** \[CapitalDelta]N (!)`

```
J = (.74 - N1[T, f]/sumN)^2 + (.13 - N2[T, f]/sumN)^2 + (.11 -N3[T, f]/sumN)^2
opt = NMinimize[{J , \[CapitalDelta]N > 0 }, {T, f, \[CapitalDelta]N}]
(*{5.79983*10^-12, {T -> 0.00119306,f -> 0.937932, \[CapitalDelta]N ->0.0112501}}*)

{N1[T, f], N2[T, f], N3[T, f]} /. opt[[2]]
(*{0.416216, 0.0731177, 0.0618699}*)
```

Comment: The fundamental problem is that only the *relative* proportions are known. It is not known that `N1[T, f]` should be `.74`, etc. It is just known that `N1[T, f]/Total[Table[Ni[T, f], {Ni, {N1, N2, ...}]]` should be `.74`.

Comment: ... Total[Ni]=N1+N2+N3=?=.98`?

Comment: Not quite. The sum of them is unknown as far as I can tell. The *percentages* they comprise are known, though.

Comment: Sorry , I'm out. What about your comment "...updated version where I take N1 + N2 + N3 == .98 ..."

Comment: Laziness in writing on my part. I took them to be .98 of the total.

Comment: @b3m2a1 is correct, I don't know the total number of molecules (N1, N2, N3) at any given point, I do know the percent of the solution that is N1, N2, N3.

Comment: I'm slightly more suspicious of the result of @UlrichNeumann because the value for T is quite low.  Looking at $N_1$ and $N_2$, if one takes the ratio, $f$ will cancel out, so T can be calculated roughly and the value agrees rather well with b3m2a1's solution.  I needed a better solution to treat all three equations at the same time, but I would be surprised if adding in $N_3$ changed $T$ by two orders of magnitude.

Comment: @  Mecury-197  I edited my answer (hopefully I now get the meaning of `N1,N2,N3`

Comment: @  Mecury-197  I edited my answer (hopefully I now got the right meaning of `N1,N2,N3` )

Comment: @UlrichNeumann this is a good solution too, thanks!